# how to put icon vertically and horizontally center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have an icon to be vertically and horizontally centered to the div.

```css
.exhibitor_image_div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: thin black solid;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px ;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.exhibitor_image_default_icon{
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    top: 50%;
}


 span i {
     font-size: 65px;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="exhibitor_image_div">
    <div class="exhibitor_image_default_icon">
        <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have given **50%** from top. but it is not vertically centered.

Comment: FYI you no longer need `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefixes for border-radius [unless you're specificlally targeting Firefox 3.6 or Chrome 4 and earlier](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius) from 2009/2010. (But those are the browsers that have auto-updating, so this is exceptionally unlikely.)

Comment: yes.. but i m supposed to follow such rules that's why I have written these

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CSS transform to move the icon up 50% of its height, and thus center the icon in its parent element.

```css
.exhibitor_image_div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: thin black solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px ;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.exhibitor_image_default_icon {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  // border: thin red solid;
}
span i {
  font-size: 65px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="exhibitor_image_div">
  <div class="exhibitor_image_default_icon">
    <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the awesome property `calc`, to `calculate 50% - image height`

Take a look at the example, i've just adde the calc property to the css

```css
.exhibitor_image_div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: thin black solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px ;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.exhibitor_image_default_icon{
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  top: calc(50% - 35px);
  // border: thin red solid;
}
span i{
  font-size: 65px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="exhibitor_image_div">
  <div class="exhibitor_image_default_icon">
    <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: cheers @Rishi, calc is one of the best things I've discovered in css.

Comment: This is good if you have specific pixel dimensions, but fails with responsive design.

Comment: @Kyle what do you mean by fails with responsive design? The whole example is pixel defined, I've used calc in other responsive designs and it has no problems at all.

Comment: Calc will work in responsive design, and agreed the OP is using pixel units, I was just pointing out that calc(50% - 35px); where 35px is a hard unit, unresponsive, then that will fail. Nothing more than that :)

Answer (score 0):

Used CSS `transform` for horizontal  center of the parent using `translateY(-50%)`

```css
.exhibitor_image_div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: thin black solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px ;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.exhibitor_image_default_icon{
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  top: 50%;
  // border: thin red solid;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

span i{
  font-size: 65px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="exhibitor_image_div">

  <div class="exhibitor_image_default_icon">
    <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` on the parent and add a `flex-grow: 1;` div above and below the icon. The growing divs will then divide the available space evenly between them and vertically center the icon.

With this it does not matter how large the centered div is.

[browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

```css
.exhibitor_image_div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: thin black solid;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px ;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;

    /* New */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

 .exhibitor_image_default_icon{
     height: 70px;
     width: 70px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     position:relative;
     /*border: thin red solid;*/
 }


 span i {
     font-size: 65px;
 }


 /* New */
 .flex_grow {
     flex-grow: 1;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="exhibitor_image_div">
    <div class="flex_grow"></div><!-- HERE -->
    <div class="exhibitor_image_default_icon">
        <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> </span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex_grow"></div><!-- HERE -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this article to be quite helpful - https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

However in relation to your problem specifically - you just need to add 1 line of code:

```
.exhibitor_image_default_icon{
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); <-- new line of code 
    /* add the browser specific transform */
}
```

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chris2001/orfp8bb4/1/

Answer (score 0):

Minimalistic flexbox solution: just add to item `margin: auto` (of course, add `display: flex` to containter). This will center item both horizontally and vertically. And you don't have to deal with absolutely positioned blocks.

Final code, removed redundant styles:

```css
.exhibitor_image_div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: thin black solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.exhibitor_image_default_icon {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  margin: auto;
}

span i {
  font-size: 65px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="exhibitor_image_div">
  <div class="exhibitor_image_default_icon">
    <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```